# Make Objects of Gridpane fill screen

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

I am currently trying to learn JavaFX. I have created a small setup with a Gridpane shown in the screenshot below

[image]

I made the background of the gridpane red so as you can see it fills the whole screen. But unfortunately the labels and textfields stay the same size. I want them to scale with the size of the gridpane.

Below is the code at the moment:

```
   @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test Application");

    grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    grid.setPrefSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    grid.setMinSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    textWelcome = new Text("Welcome");
    textWelcome.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    grid.add(textWelcome, 0, 0, 2, 1);

    labelName = new Label("User Name: ");
    grid.add(labelName, 0,1);

    nameField = new TextField();
    grid.add(nameField, 1,1);

    labelPW = new Label("Password: ");
    grid.add(labelPW,0,2);

    pwField = new PasswordField();
    grid.add(pwField,1,2);

    buttonSign = new Button("Sign in");
    HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    hBox.getChildren().add(buttonSign);
    grid.add(hBox,1,3);

    grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
    //grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    scene = new Scene(grid, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

So now i want to know on how to make the whole thing scale up so that there is not a big margin at the sides.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ColumnConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) and [`RowConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html) to configure the behavior of the columns and rows. You can also set properties on individual nodes using the static `GridPane` methods.

See the sections entitled "Row/Column Sizing" and "Optional Layout Constraints" in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)

Here is a simple example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GridPaneColumnGrowExample extends Application {

    private static final double WINDOW_WIDTH = 600 ;
    private static final double WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Application");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setPrefSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        grid.setMinSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        leftCol.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);

        Text textWelcome = new Text("Welcome");
        textWelcome.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(textWelcome, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        // override column constraints alignment for this cell
        GridPane.setHalignment(textWelcome, HPos.LEFT);

        Label labelName = new Label("User Name: ");
        grid.add(labelName, 0,1);

        TextField nameField = new TextField();
        grid.add(nameField, 1,1);

        Label labelPW = new Label("Password: ");
        grid.add(labelPW,0,2);

        PasswordField pwField = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(pwField,1,2);

        Button buttonSign = new Button("Sign in");
        grid.add(buttonSign,1,3);
        GridPane.setHalignment(buttonSign, HPos.RIGHT);

        grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
        //grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but i now just resorted to using the Scene Builder. Its definitly less frustating than doing it in the code

Comment: You can set all those properties directly in Scene Builder. It doesn't really make any difference how you write the code, it still has to be written somehow.